# How to create aurora with unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to create beautiful aurora at game background

How to create aurora with unity3D?

If it is difficult to explain, please tell me what i have to learn

Comment: You could do it with a simple animated texture, overlayed on the sky background. Of course that presumes you've got a graphic artist capable of creating something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own skybox. I am not sure if they can play a gif/video, but they might be able to. Otherwise you could just create your own by using light.
To create your own with particles and emitters I would just make many beams of light and then change the color and location to simulate an aurora, but this might be difficult to get a real looking aurora.